# Approximate Nearest Neighbor Search

Tags: computational-statistics, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to find information on choosing an optimal k for approximate nearest neighbor search using locality sensitive hashing (LSH) on a large data set. k represents the number of nearest neighbors being considered when determining your classification. It seems choosing this k is an essential part of finding an accurate solution, but I haven't found any reliable methods to do so. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: A common approach is based on the [title of this site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation+k-nearest-neighbour).

Comment: I think the way you pick k would be the same as if you were doing the regular non approximate nearest neighbor search

Comment: You're after the optimal number of clusters ($k$) in a dataset.   Obviously, you need to assess the objective function (final output) as a function of $k$.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the Theorem 7 of this paper: [Fast k-Nearest Neighbour Search via Dynamic Continuous Indexing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00442v2.pdf).